# Vue - Supabase error while doing NPM run npm

Tags: vue.js, vercel, vite, supabase

So I have a Vue application that I was working on. Later I wanted to add a backend to it using Supabase and deploy to Vercel. However, after I added the backend elements to it, it throws the following error when I did `npm run serve`:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                            1:31:54 PM

 error  in ./src/supabase.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:24)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
> var supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL;
| var supabaseAnonKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;
| export var supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
```

Anyone knows what this means? I have another Vue app that was set up via Vite and it ran fine in local, but not in this Vue app that wasn't set up by Vite.

Answer (score 3):

change your .env variable from VITE_SUPABASE_URL to VUE_APP_SUPABASE_URL and import.meta.env to process.env.

Example:

From this

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
```

To this

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.VUE_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
```